# Determining FirstOfferDateTime in a Healthcare Scheduling Scenario using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on an SQL script where I need to accurately calculate the `FirstOfferDateTime` for patient appointments based on specific criteria.

The scenario involves several datetime variables: `EventDateTime`, `AppointmentDateTime`, and `ScreenDate`.

The primary condition is that both `EventDateTime` and `AppointmentDateTime` should be after the `ScreenDate`.

The complexity arises in handling appointment cancellations and rescheduling:

If the hospital cancels an appointment and reschedules it to an earlier date, the `FirstOfferDateTime` should be updated to this new, earlier date.

Conversely, if a patient cancels and the appointment is rescheduled (regardless of whether the new date is before or after the original date), the `FirstOfferDateTime` should remain as the original date and the same is true for the appointments that did not attend (DNA) or attended.

For instance, consider a case where the given `ScreenDate` is **15/03/2023**. From the following table, the hospital initially offered an appointment for **19/06/2023 12:00**, but then the hospital cancelled and rescheduled it to **27/05/2023 09:00** and then again hospital cancelled and rescheduled it to **04/05/2023 09:00**, therefore, the `FirstOfferDateTime` should be **04/05/2023 09:00** since the next appointment date is also cancelled by hospital, is after this date.

I am seeking assistance in developing a logic or algorithm to handle these conditions. Any suggestions or guidance on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

| EventDateTime | AppointmentDateTime | AppointmentStatus | CancelledBy | FirstOfferDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22/02/2023 13:00 | 02/03/2023 10:00 | Cancelled | Hospital | ? |
| 22/02/2023 13:00 | 03/03/2023 10:00 | Attended |  | ? |
| 29/03/2023 15:00 | 19/06/2023 12:00 | Cancelled | Hospital | ? |
| 29/03/2023 15:00 | 27/05/2023 09:00 | Cancelled | Hospital | ? |
| 29/03/2023 15:00 | 04/05/2023 09:00 | Cancelled | Hospital | ? |
| 01/04/2023 14:00 | 06/05/2023 10:00 | Cancelled | Hospital | ? |
| 02/04/2023 13:00 | 27/05/2023 09:00 | Cancelled | Patient | ? |
| 03/03/2024 09:00 | 29/06/2023 09:00 | Attended |  | ? |
| 04/04/2024 10:00 | 17/07/2023 13:00 | Attended |  | ? |
| 04/04/2024 11:00 | 29/08/2023 10:00 | Cancelled | Patient | ? |

So far my proposed solution is as follows.

1. Declare the following variable tables with Id int identity primary key

   ```
    @appointmentsInOrder0...20 but if more than 20 events happen, then this wouldn't work, 
    @appointmentsInOrderFinal(... also AppointmentOrder int)
   ```
2. Insert initial appointments for the patient from a source into `@appointmentsInOrder0`
3. Recursively check `@appointmentsInOrder0...20`
   if `AppointmentStatus` is `Cancelled` and `CancelledBy` is `Hospital`,
   then if `@currentAppointmentDate > @nextAppointmentDate`
   then insert @nextAppointmentDate into @appointmentsInOrder(+1)
   followed by another insert @currentAppointmentDate into @appointmentsInOrder(+1)
   skip next
   else
   insert @currentAppointmentDate into @appointmentsInOrder(+1)
   else insert @currentAppointmentDate into @appointmentsInOrder(+1)
4. From `@appointmentsInOrder20` insert into `@appointmentsInOrderFinal`
5. `SELECT * FROM @appointmentsInOrderFinal ORDER BY AppointmentOrder`

I am facing challenges with the efficiency and accuracy of the above approach, particularly in the recursive checking and final data retrieval steps. Any alternative methods to streamline this process or point to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably put the expected result offerdate into your table. The ? doesn't really help anything

Comment: Yes, however, this is the column to be populated; therefore, for the given scenario, the FirstOfferDateTime would be populated 04/05/2023 09:00. And another example, if the given screen date is 20/02/2023 then the first offer date would be 02/03/2023.

Comment: Well, then add a column called ExpectedFirstOfferDateTime :) It's easier to test one's code against a table instead of parsing text of texts

Comment: Thank you for helping. ExpectedFirstOfferDateTime is also known as a BreachDate, where the patient must be offered an appointment within this expected date. However, the first offer date is an actual date given to the patient and doing min() order will not work if there are hospital cancellations in the appointments

Comment: ' therefore, the FirstOfferDateTime should be 04/05/2023 09:00 since the next appointment date is also cancelled by hospital, ' there is no logic which can be applied to this..

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of your data? Does `EventDateTime` refer to the action date/time where an appointment was either created, canceled, or attended? If not, we would need a timestamp of some sort to order the actions. How do we know which rows are related to the same appointment (including reschedulings of the same) in contrast to separate (follow-up or unrelated) appointments? A non-iterative solution would likely involve *window functions* that have `OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)` and we would need unambiguous values to insert there.

Comment: Your data has two rows with `AppointmentDateTime = 27/05/2023 09:00`, once canceled by the hospital and one canceled by the patient. How should this be interpreted? Was the appointment scheduled, canceled, restored, and canceled again?

Comment: I think the answer might involve using *conditional aggregation* in a *window function* that filters appointment actions by initial scheduling and rescheduling by hospital -   Something along the lines of `MIN(CASE WHEN IsInitialScheduling = 1 OR IsReschedulingByHospital = 1) THEN AppointmentDateTime END) OVER(PARTITION BY AppointmentGroup) AS FirstOfferDateTime`, where `IsInitialScheduling`, `IsReschedulingByHospital` and `AppointmentGroup` are calculated elsewhere. Since your supplied sample data does not include a representation of `ScreenDate`, I am unsure how that would be included.